# Why did Docker get stopped on unattended upgrades

Tags: 18.04, unattended-upgrades

The Docker daemon gets stopped and not restarted after unattended upgrades.
Is this normal?
Im using Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

```
Dec 01 06:39:19 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Dec 01 06:39:26 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
```

Comment: Is it when containerd is being upgraded as per here https://serverfault.com/questions/1044493/how-to-make-sure-docker-service-will-start-after-containerd-upgrade? Your question probably needs more information.

Comment: Is there any evidence that this was a defect in the update pushed yesterday? It is atypical for Docker to not restart after an update. Certainly it is safer to not use unattended upgrades, but in principle they should work, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [bug in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/containerd/+bug/1870514) which caused this shutdown of dockerd. It occurred because of an automatic security update of containerd. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/1044493/how-to-make-sure-docker-service-will-start-after-containerd-upgrade.

The previously accepted answer disables the automatic security updates, so be aware of the consequences.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu has a hidden auto-upgrade program, and it sometimes crashes your system by terminating docker. (My server went down for 5 hours because of this issue)

To fix this bug, just disable `apt-daily-upgrade.timer.service` on all your ubuntu servers. Usually, even without this bug, we don't want slient upgrade which may cause service interruption.

```bsh
sudo systemctl disable --now apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

Ref: https://arun.nz/why-does-docker-restart-all-containers-regularly/

Comment: In such case, how you maintain that daily updates? Manually, every week or smth? 
I'm looking for good practices :)

Comment: @Aurimas I manually trigger a upgrade task for all my servers twice a month. (a simple SSH command inside for-loop) After finishing the bi-monthly upgrade, I wait for several minutes and check my realtime monitor board, to make sure all services are healthy.

Comment: thanks! Could you share your script for manually triggering of the update task? :)

Comment: @Aurimas This is a naive script for only 5 servers, you may look at it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pQKnMZM7MB/